# Timeline from diferent wordpress api urls endpoint works, but diferent date

Tags: functions, rest-api

i created this snipped code to display in timeline wrap post title and post time, and it's work. But my problem is i see the las 10 posts but diferent date, the idea is display the 10 las recently post published y any websites getting from api rest data. So my question is, why if put all data in merge variable, do not print the last recently.

```
function pl_last_10_posts_timeline_shortcode() {
    
    // API endpoints
    $urls = [
        'https://site1/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
        'https://site2/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',      
        'https://site3/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'      
    ];

    // Empty posts array   
    $posts = [];

    // Retrieve posts     
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $response = wp_remote_get($url); 
        // Check response     
        $body =  wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);   
        $json_data = json_decode($body);  
        if (is_array($json_data)) {
            $posts = array_merge($posts, $json_data);
        }
    }

    // Sort posts by date and time in descending order
    // Sort posts by date in descending order 
usort($posts, function($a, $b) {
    $a_date = strtotime($a->date . ' ' . $a->time);
    $b_date = strtotime($b->date . ' ' . $b->time);
    if ($a_date == $b_date) {
        return 0; 
    }
    return ($a_date < $b_date) ? 1 : -1;
});

// Only keep the 10 most recent posts 
$posts = array_slice($posts, 0, 10);   


    // HTML    

    // Loop through the posts and add them to the timeline
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $html .= '<div class="timeline-item">';
        $html .= '<div class="timeline-item-content">';
        $html .= '<span class="timeline-item-time">' . date( 'F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime( $post->date . ' ' . $post->time ) ) . '</span>';
        $html .= '<h2 class="timeline-item-title"><a href="' . $post->guid . '">' . $post->title . '</a></h2>';
        $html .= '</div></div>';
    }

    // Wrap the timeline HTML in a container div
    $html = '<div class="timeline-container">' . $html . '</div>';

    // Return the HTML
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode( 'pl_last_10_posts_timeline', 'pl_last_10_posts_timeline_shortcode' );
```

Comment: are you asking how to sort the results you fetched by date? Or are you saying that the results being returned are incorrect? If the sorting is incorrect then what do you get instead?

Comment: What I am saying is that the results are not quite right, it returns 10 posts from the different websites, it sorts them well by time, however they are not the 10 most recent posts, I guess if you check the urls, search by date and time, publish among them which are the last published and this is what is not happening

Comment: if your last post on the site A was in 2022, then the 10 most recent posts it sends are from 2022, even if 50 posts were written on site B in 2023. If you want the 10 most recent posts from each individual site then you can request the last 10 posts, but it doesn't work if you want to do it globally, and in a worst case scenario you'd have to request _all_ posts from _all_ sites to be sure you have 100% accuracy all the time in all situations, which doesn't scale. What's the reason for doing this? Are these sites on the same multisite?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, the sites are independent, not multisites, the idea is that these sites respond to different sections of a news portal, the idea is to show the posts from all the sites as they are published in a widget that gathers the last 10 o 15 most recent posts, these 10 or 15 posts come from all three sites but if the last 10 or more are from the same site because they are the 10 most recent, you should be seeing that. However, you tell me that I cannot obtain it with that precision?

Comment: because if the most recent 20 posts are from a single site then you can't know that if you only fetch 10 posts from each site. If posts 11-20 on site A are newer than the 10 most recent posts on site B, then the results will be incorrect. What you've described doesn't sound consistent logically though, how are you testing this? Are the expected posts present if you remove the `array_slice`? Have you confirmed personally that each endpoint returns what you expect by looking at it directly? Or are you only running the entire code from start to end and seeing it didn't work?

Comment: I have it my friend, and it's all my fault, thanks to your comment, I checked the rest api urls separately, and in effect it only gave me the result of 5, and this is because I had previously created a function to give me a custom api rest data, and there I had it defined only for 5 posts, I have increased it and that's it !!!! everything working great!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your comments, this is the function I was talking about... Thanks again

Comment: Custom Api rest data, creating custom routes. 

`function wl_posts() {
 $args = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 10
 ];
      $posts = get_posts($args);
      $data = [];
   $i = 0;
 foreach($posts as $post) {
  $data[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
  $data[$i]['title'] = $post->post_title;
        $data[$i]['excerpt'] = $post->post_excerpt;
        
        $data ... [ MORE DATA] 
  
$i++;
 }
 return $data;
  }
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
 register_rest_route('wl/v1', 'posts', [
  'methods' => 'GET',
  'callback' => 'wl_posts',
 ]);
`

Comment: can you edit it into your question? Comments don't support code blocks and your question should contain _everything_ needed to answer and understand the question. If you've found a solution post it below in the larger box as an answer rather than as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the rest api urls separately, and i realice it only print the result of 5 posts for each url site, and this is because I had previously created a function to display a custom api rest data, and there I had it defined only for 5 posts, I have increased it and that's it !!!! everything working great!!!!

So, 1 - The code works sucessfully!!! and 2- This it's my custom api rest ( Create route and including Aadvanced custom fields data.

```
function wl_posts() {   

$args = [   
    'post_type' => 'post',      
    'posts_per_page' => 10  ];    


    $posts = get_posts($args);       
    
    $data = [];       
    $i = 0;     
    foreach($posts as $post) {      
    $data[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;        
    $data[$i]['title'] = $post->post_title;         
    $data[$i]['excerpt'] = $post->post_excerpt;                  
    $data ... [ MORE DATA]           
    
    $i++;   }   
    return $data;   } 
    
    add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('wl/v1', 'posts', [         
    'methods' => 'GET',         
    'callback' => 'wl_posts',   ]);
```